# Ambiguous meaning of NAmEng sense of "skill" in Harrap's English-French Dictionary

Tags: american-english, word-usage, dialects, north-american-english, vernacular

[Harrap's New Shorter](http://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/harrap's-shorter-french-english-dictionary-french/) English-French/French-English Dictionary, Ed. 1982, states,

> ***skill***
>
> *n*
>
> **1.** habileté *f*, adresse *f*, dextérité *f*; **technical skill,** habileté, aptitude *f*, technique; compétence *f* technique; **skill in doing sth,** (i) talent *m*, habileté *f*, pour faire qqch.; (ii) art *m* de faire qqch.; **lack of skill,** maladresse *f*, inhabileté *f*.
>
> **2.** *North American:* [métier](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/fr/traduire/francais-anglais/metier); art *m* pratique.

Question is, considering that "métier" carries quite a lot of nuances in French (as you can see in the links below), and that "art pratique" (*lit.* "practical art") is a vague phrase and, as such, sounds kind of confusing as to what is actually meant, what exactly is that North American meaning of "skill" supported here by British Harrap?

Also, if that second sense of "skill" actually *is* specific to North American English, what would be the British English equivalent for it?

***métier***

> [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/m%C3%A9tier)
>
> 1. Exercice d'un art mécanique. *Le métier de cordonnier, de tailleur, de serrurier, de tisserand, etc*. *Apprendre, savoir, avoir, exercer un métier*. *Il est maçon de son métier*.
>
> (Practice of a mechanical craft. *The trade of shoemaker, tailor, locksmith, weaver, etc.* *Learn, be proficient in, have, follow a trade*. *He's a mason by trade*.)
>
> 5. Habileté d'exécution, mais rien de plus, en parlant de la peinture, de la sculpture ; le talent acquis de vaincre facilement la matière. Avoir du métier.
>
> (Skill of execution, but nothing more, with reference to painting, sculpture; the acquired talent to easily vanquish matter. *To have skill/technique*.)
>
> [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/m%C3%A9tier)
>
> A. − Activité manuelle ou mécanique nécessitant l'acquisition d'un savoir-faire, d'une pratique.
>
> (Manual or mechanical occupation requiring the acquisition of a *savoir-faire*, of a practical skill.)
>
> D. − *Par métonymie*. Habileté, savoir-faire dans la production ou l'exécution manuelle ou intellectuelle acquise par l'expérience, la pratique que confère un métier ou une activité permanente.
>
> (*By metonymy*. Skill, know-how in the manual/intellectual production or execution acquired through experience and practice in a regular trade or occupation.)

***skill***

> [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skill)
>
> *n.*
>
> a. Proficiency, facility, or dexterity that is acquired or developed through training or experience: *painted with great skill*.
>
> b. A developed talent or ability: *improved his writing skills*.
>
> c. An art, trade, or technique, particularly one requiring use of the hands or body: *the skill of glassmaking*.
>
> **Synonyms**: skill, art, craft, expertise, know-how, technique
>   These nouns denote great ability in doing or performing that is attained especially by study or practice: *a shortstop legendary for his fielding skill*; *mosaics rendered with exquisite art*; *pottery that reveals an artist's craft*; *a woodworker with special expertise in parquet floors*; *mechanical know-how*; *played the violin with impeccable technique*.
>
> American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011
>
> *n*
>
> 1. special ability in a task, sport, etc, esp ability acquired by training
> 2. something, esp a trade or technique, requiring special training or manual proficiency
>
> Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014
>
> *n.*
>
> 1. the ability, coming from one's knowledge, practice, aptitude, etc., to do something well: *Carpentry was one of his many skills*.
> 2. competent excellence in performance; expertness; dexterity:
>      *The dancers performed with skill*.
> 3. a craft, trade, or job requiring manual dexterity or special training in which a person has competence and experience: *the skill of cabinetmaking*.
>
> Random House Dictionary, © 2011

Comment: Surely you have encountered a *skilled amateur*, who is not in the trade?

Comment: @TimLymington Actually, I can't seem to understand the translation of "skill" into French "métier" supported by Harrap's New Shorter and marked as North American usage...How would "skill" differ from "trade" or "craft" in the sense "métier"?

Comment: One might say "I'm a clockmaker by trade" (if that's one's business) or perhaps "by training" (if that is what one is qualified to do) but not *by skill* or *by craft*.

Comment: I have encountered "craft" as a subdivision of "trade" in collective bargaining agreements but this seems to be a term of art per union contract (for example in your school district,  teachers and classroom aides might be in the same trade of education, but different crafts as they might have different schedules or responsibilities in the agreement).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (after clarification) it seems to be about the correct translation in North America of French *metier*. As such it would fit French.SE better; otherwise editing would clarify.

Comment: By the time I finished reading the post I'd forgotten what the question was. What is your question by the way? Oh, wait the dictionary is saying the second meaning of skill is  *métier* in American English. And you're asking.... what do other native speakers  use in place of it?  I don't see the connection between "art of" or "manual trade" and "practical art". In other words, is the premise of your question based on a single dictionary entry by Harrap? What does the bounty message mean by the current answers are "out of date", they're two days old! :)

Comment: Would *métier* be what you would call a career made out of a trade skill? English isn't the only confusing language, after all... :)

Comment: It might be best to tell us what the question is at the END, and explain the pertinence of the Ngrams. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learnt+the+skill%2Clearnt+the+craft%2Clearnt+the+trade%2Clearnt+the+mestiere&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clearnt%20the%20skill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearnt%20the%20craft%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearnt%20the%20trade%3B%2Cc0) showing the British English results for *learnt the trade, learnt the skill, learnt the craft*. The first is the most popular. Use the pp *learned* for the AmEng Ngram.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, I already checked that before posting the Ngrams. For some reason, "'learned' the craft from" is the most popular spelling in BrEng... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learned+the+skill+from%2Clearned+the+craft+from%2Clearnt+the+skill+from%2C%2Clearnt+the+craft+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clearned%20the%20craft%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearnt%20the%20craft%20from%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Some confusion can arise because 'metier' is a borrowing into English (with its own connotations)

Comment: Did you do the translators trick of going back and forth, to see what an E-F dictionary says 'métier' is in English (I doubt it is 'skill')

Comment: Have you looked at other dictionaries? Also, answering this question well necessitates a command of French also, its subtle nuances. You probably want to _discuss_ your question at a translation site (I recommend dict.leo).

Comment: I am baffled as to why you think *trade, craft* (which you find in your dictionary links as translations of *métier*) aren't sufficient answers to this question. If you answered this, maybe we could give an answer closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mitch Thing is, Harrap doesn't provide much information, aside from the fact that this sense of "skill" is chiefly NAm. No examples, no BrEng equivalent.... Other dictionaries like Collins-Robert don't support a NAm sense to skill. Apparently, Harrap knows best ;-).

Comment: @PeterShor Is "skill" actually another word in NAmEng for "trade"/"craft"? If so, could you please provide examples of how Americans use "skill" in the sense "métier; art pratique"?

Comment: @Elian: Yes, although it's not an exact synonym; that is, it can't always be used to replace these. See the [synonym discussion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skill) in Merriam-Webster and [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=skill). .

Comment: @PeterShor OK. Then, if "skill" is chiefly NAm in the sense "technical knowledge and proficiency," as in "the skill of a glassblower," would the BrEng equivalent for that be "the craft of a glassblower"?

Comment: *"The skill of a glassblower"* and *"the craft of a glassblower"* mean nearly the same thing in NAm English, although maybe *"the craft"* is a little broader. I don't know what *"skill of a glassblower"* would mean in British English.

Comment: @PeterShor Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: @Elian You're asking very important questions... but I fear they need a kind of knowledge of all of French, AmE, BrE, the editing of Harrap's and other dictionaries MW, AHD, etc that you're unlikely to find here.

Comment: Is your question then "What do you say for 'métier' in BrE or AusE? (given that dictionaries imply that 'skill' is only used for it in NAm)"

Comment: I think you should go back to the people who wrote that dictionary. :)

Comment: @Mitch Actually, I needed to "pin down" what is meant by "skill" in the sense "métier; art pratique," because these words carry a lot of nuances in French. And so, a BrEng or AusEng équivalent might have helped...

Comment: @elian then what exactly is your primary question? It is not clear. You have a lot of info there, but not a clear question. Please give a primary question, and clearly separate that from subsidiary questions.

Comment: You may need to change your question title. It sounds like you're really asking "What do British and Australian English speakers use in place of North American English 'trade skill' (Fr. *métier*)?"... because your dictionary implies that North America uses "skill" this way and other regions don't.

Comment: @TimWard That North America uses "skill" in the sense "métier; art pratique" and other regions don't is indeed what my dictionary implies.

Comment: Elian, I hope you can find an answer from the group here, but I don't know that you will be able to find *the* answer. Also, I've added a little bit more to my answer you might find interesting.

Comment: Related:[How common is the French loanword “métier”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225049/how-common-is-the-french-loanword-m%C3%A9tier) Sven Yarg's answer is very good. I forgot to link the question earlier. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skill) [2014]

> *skill* ... n
>
> 1. special ability in a task, sport, etc, esp ability acquired by training
> 2. something, esp a trade or technique, requiring special training or manual proficiency
> 3. obsolete understanding

lists the senses in order of frequency of usage as found in their corpus data; both the 'special ability' and the 'trade/technique calling for sense [1]' polysemes are listed. This issue is not confined to US usage.

Where there is scope for ambiguity ('Manual crafts developed quite quickly during this time') [note from say [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/craft) that '*craft*' also has both 'skill' and 'skill-requiring occupation' senses; distribution of usages is by no means identical, though), it may be considered that there is little need to distinguish these senses. If there is such a need, only the principle polyseme (eg skill = special ability) should be used, or a workaround employed.

The loan-word **métier** [[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/m%C3%A9tier)]:

> 1. An occupation, trade, or profession
> 2. Work or activity for which a person is particularly suited; one's specialty

might actually be used to disambiguate in some cases.

Rephrasing with better context might be preferable:

> 'Local industries – manual crafts – developed quite quickly during
>   this time.'
>
> 'The manual skills of the typical villager developed quite quickly
>   during this time.'

Comment: Do you understand what the OP's question is? Because I'm quite confused.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think the question is actually based on 'usage extension' of the term "skill" rather than on actual meaning.

Comment: @Josh61 well, I might *think* that myself, but the question is quite unclear despite all the research.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - it originally was about the difference between trade and skill meaning "job" in AmE, but now I don't know  what the question is.

Comment: (a) (implied): 'Is this latter sense of "skill" (= Collins sense {2}:
something, esp a **trade** or technique, requiring special training / manual proficiency [/ Collins sense {1}])   still[?] specific to North American English?' //// (b) What would **other native speakers** of English say to render what "métier; art pratique" is to French?

Answer (score 3):

A trade is an occupation - generally requiring specialized knowledge and skill(s), and performed for compensation.

A craft is an activity requiring some specialized skill(s), but the term implies nothing with respect to compensation. Knitting, carving, pottery making are all crafts, but not necessarily trades.

A skill is a specific ability. A given craft or trade may actually call for a set of skills in order for a practitioner to be successful.

Comment: You are just giving the principle senses here, without discussing the ambiguities involved.

Comment: @edwin Anthony distinguishes the three terms

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is this: How does *métier* differ from simple *skill*?

The answer is probably part anthropological and part cultural.

In English, the term *métier* was inherited from French in the 18th Century and applied to professions that required a particular skill or 'calling'. This was a period when culturally we were at the end of the transition from feudalism to the more capitalist system in place through most of Western civilization today.

In terms of professions where this term, *métier*, might be applied, refer to the Online Etymology Dictionary's entry:

> "skill, talent, calling," 1792, from French *métier* "trade,
>   profession," from Old French *mestier* "task, affair, service, function,
>   duty," from Gallo-Roman * *misterium*, from Latin *ministerium* "office,
>   service," from *minister* "servant" (see minister (n.)).

In English today, we still refer to these as ***trade skills***, and many of the professional careers that require special skills also have professional guilds or unions.

In modern usage, the term can be applied to whatever you would call your *career* or even your *area of expertise*.

Edited to add:

An interesting term related to this is *vocational education*, which is the study and practice of skills related to such ***vocational careers***. Again, many of these careers also have related guilds or unions that support the collective employees.

There's also an interesting mini-surge in popularity of "trade skill" around 1920. If you compare [this Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trade%20skill%2Cmetier%2Cm%C3%A9tier%2Cvocational%20education&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrade%20skill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmetier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cm%C3%A9tier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvocational%20education%3B%2Cc0) searching on "trade skill,metier,métier,vocational education", you see an incredible spike in "vocational education" around that same time. Ironically, it seems that the phrase "vocational career" has remained mostly flat, [about even with "trade skill" overall](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trade%20skill%2Cvocational%20career&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrade%20skill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvocational%20career%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Elian, I saw you posted an edit to your original, but I think my answer still stands. Although, I'm a bit unsure what you mean when you say *If this latter sense of "skill" actually is specific to North American English, what would other native speakers of English say to render what "métier; art pratique" is to French?* Are you looking for an alternative French term? If not, I think **trade skill** (for *art pratique*) and **career** are perfectly acceptable translations.

Answer (score 1):

If, after sorting through the excellent and meticulous lexicography presented here, I understand the core of the question to seek a word in common American use, I would offer from my storehouse of everyday speech the word *artisan* and its variant forms *artisanal* and *artisanship* as locutions commonly used, perhaps overused, and nonetheless evident in the American marketplace. Once reserved for skilled craftsmanship, the adjective form in particular is now attached to everything from white bread to lite beer.

Answer (score 0):

The more common meanings of the two terms according to the AHD are:

[Skill](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skill):

> - 1)  Proficiency, facility, or dexterity that is acquired or developed through training or experience: painted with great skill.

[Trade](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trade):

> - 1) The business of buying and selling commodities, products, or services; commerce.

Regarding the definitions you are citing, I'd say that:

- ***A trade*** is used to refer to an occupation or a particular area of business or industry. e.g. the book trade, the clothing trade.

while:

- ***A skill*** is the ability to do or perform something with a high level of competence , usually gained through experience and training.

Comment: Don't think this is quite right.  There are plenty of references like "he's a carpenter by trade."

Comment: This answer does not address e.g. "building trades" in the OP and as a very common United States union: http://mobile.philly.com/news/?wss=/philly/news&id=323999151&